# How to show enumerator's integral value?

Tags: cc-mode

Is there a way to print out the integral value of enumerator?

I tried to search related questions but no good. So I suspect that this isn't a common requirement for most of people. But I do occasionally need to know the integer, the enumerator representing.

For IDE, usually this can be accomplished when hovering the cursor above the specified enumerator.

**Update**

As an example, the following listing illustrates what I want. The vertical bar (┃) indicates where the cursor/point is.

```c
enum FOO
{
  FOO_A = 0,
  FOO_B,
  FOO_C┃,
};
```

After hovering over for a short period, I expect to see the integral value of `FOO_C` to be 2.

Comment: Please give an example of what you are trying to find the answer to.

Comment: Have you tried lsp?

Comment: @TerryTsao Tried one of lsp, clangd. It works.